# merge dfs that have similar column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 large pandas dfs, where the first one contains various IDs a specific student. The other one has one or more of the IDs that match. I want to merge the dfs such that it will combine based on if df2 has a value found in df1.

DF1:

```
ID                 name
nfi23, wjm348      sally
hji21, arb128      joe
mbi13, ybm328      mary
```

DF2

```
ID                       grade        
nfi23                    twelfth       
arb128, hji21            third
mbi13                    fourth
```

desired:

```
ID                 name         grade
nfi23, wjm348      sally        twelfth
hji21, arb128      joe          third
mbi13, ybm328      mary         fourth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Break the ids apart.
df1.ID = df1.ID.str.split(', ')
df2.ID = df2.ID.str.split(', ')
df1 = df1.explode('ID')
df2 = df2.explode('ID')

# Merge on ID
out = (df1.merge(df2, 'left')
          .groupby('name') # Bring it all back together~
          .agg(set)
          .applymap(lambda x: ', '.join(i for i in x if isinstance(i, str)))
          .reset_index())
print(out)
```

Output:

```
    name             ID    grade
0    joe  hji21, arb128    third
1   mary  ybm328, mbi13   fourth
2  sally  nfi23, wjm348  twelfth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with explode then we can do map

```
df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].str.split(',')
df2 = df2.explode('ID')
df1['grade'] = df1.ID.str.split(',').explode().map(df2.set_index('ID')['grade']).groupby(level=0).first()
df1
Out[774]: 
             ID   name    grade
0  nfi23,wjm348  sally  twelfth
1  hji21,arb128    joe    third
2  mbi13,ybm328   mary   fourth
```

Comment: I get this error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects-- already tried reindexing

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [['nfi23', 'wjm348'], ['hji21', 'arb128'], ['mbi13', 'ybm328']],
    'name': ['sally', 'joe', 'mary']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [['nfi23'], ['arb128', 'hji21'], ['mbi13']],
    'grade': ['twelfth', 'third', 'fourth']
})

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'name', 'grade'])
for i, (ids, name) in df1.iterrows():
    for j, ids2 in df2.ID.iteritems():
        if len(set(ids) & set(ids2)) > 0:
            break
    df.loc[i] = ids, name, df2.loc[j, 'grade']
print(df)
```

prints

| index | ID | name | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nfi23,wjm348 | sally | twelfth |
| 1 | hji21,arb128 | joe | third |
| 2 | mbi13,ybm328 | mary | fourth |

Comment: I get this error saying 'KeyError: 'grade''

Comment: works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pd.Series.map` after making a series out of split list in df1's ID and then take the first value.

```
df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].str.split(',')
df2 = df2.explode('ID')
df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].str.strip()
d = df2.set_index('ID')['grade']
df1['grade'] = df1['ID'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(',')).map(d)[0])
```

Output:

```
               ID   name    grade
0  nfi123, wjm348  sally  twelfth
1   hji21, arb128    joe    third
2   mbi13, ybm328   mary   fourth
```

Comment: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects